# I can't install libdvdcss - script not finding medibuntu, How to get DVD playback?

Tags: repository, dvd, codecs, playback

I am trying to get [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) instructions working on 12.04, I know I am connected to the internet but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
--2013-10-09 19:18:44--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/free/binary-i386/Packages
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... 88.191.127.22
Connecting to packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)|88.191.127.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-10-09 19:18:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Dynamic fetch failed; Falling back to static fetch
--2013-10-09 19:18:44--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.10-0.2medibuntu1_i386.deb
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... 88.191.127.22
Connecting to packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)|88.191.127.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-10-09 19:18:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I am trying to get DVD playback going, how can I fix this?

Comment: This is because [Medibuntu has been shutdown](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) some time ago. VideoLan is the new home for libdvdcss.

Comment: This should now be fixed, just update and try again.

Answer (score 8):

#### **UPDATE:** The fix has now been released. On 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10.

Do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then just like on [PlayingDVDs Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs):

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

(make sure to do this step, or do `sudo apt-get upgrade`)

And:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

---

### Old Information on bug

A Fix has been proposed on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/1223928) and is not yet released to fix that script(although it is not in effect yet, the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) instructions will be the same once it is released).

---

To get it released as fast as possible:

- Test out the proposed update(using instructions below)
- On the [Bug Page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/1223928), Click on the yellow icon, then "Yes, it affects me"
  [image]

  [image]
- Comment on the Launcpad page to say whether or not the update works mentioning the Ubuntu version you use(after following instructions below).

---

#### libdvdread4 percise-proposed update instructions

I am going to show you how to "[Cherry pick](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed)" the update from precise-proposed. (for releases newer than "percise" substitute with release name whenever it appears)

1. Open **Software Center** → Edit → Software Sources... → Select the **Updates** tab → Check the box "Pre-released Updates(precise-proposed)" → Then click "Close"

   [image: :pic]
2. In terminal run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
   ```

   Add the text:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=precise-proposed
   Pin-Priority: 400
   ```

   [image: :pic]
   After done entering text, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> then hit <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save changes.

   This will prevent unwanted upgrades of other packages in proposed and give you a shortcut to pick a single upgrade.
3. Now Type in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Then install `libdvdread4` with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libdvdread4/precise-proposed
   ```

   And now the new script should work using:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
   ```
4. Try out DVD(commercial) playback.

Answer (score 4):

The medibuntu website has been taken down but you can still install libdvdcss from videolan

[Here](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html)