# Something wicked happened resolving medibuntu repository, what happens?

Tags: apt

We have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machines that is giving errors when I try to run updates.

Specifically, I am getting a load of errors like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

I tried to ping packages.medibuntu.org, and it returns:

```
ping: unknown host packages.medibuntu.org
```

It therefore seems to me that sometime in the past, packages have been installed  from there, but it has 'gone away'.

Questions:

Is that diagnosis correct?

If so, how do I identify and 'fix' those packages?  Do I have to carefully go through the whole output from 'apt-get upgrade' and uninstall each one?  Hope not, but if that's what's required, then okay.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/356794/the-medibuntu-project-has-come-to-an-end-what-do-i-do-now?lq=1

Answer (score 19):

> Medibuntu has now been shut down, the packagers were either obsolete, unnecessary or moved to the official Ubuntu archive.
>
> -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu

What this means? That you should remove the repositories from your sources.list to prevent errors and look for the packages you needed somewhere else or stick with the old ones that you have installed.

Related

- [I can't install libdvdcss - script not finding medibuntu, How to get DVD playback?](https://askubuntu.com/q/356046/169736)
- [The Medibuntu Project has come to an end - what do I do now?](https://askubuntu.com/q/356794/169736)

---

### How to remove the repository:

1. Open "Software Sources";
2. Locate the Medibuntu repository;
3. Select and remove it:

[image: Software sources, removing Medibuntu repository]

Comment: I found this post from your links:

http://askubuntu.com/a/223188/200958

Should I run those commands?

What are the downside risks, and how do I mitigate if there are any?

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: @Alan use the GUI to remove them. Go to Software Sources and remove the medibuntu repositories, as you can see by the downvotes that solution is not helpful. In any case use MiJyn answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove medibuntu as a software source from the command line, edit the sources.list located in /etc/apt/

`vi /etc/apt/sources.list`

and then just comment out the line(s) that contain medibuntu.

```
...
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner
#deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free
```